# Problemas para obtener el ID de un registro dentro de un dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen dia.

Estoy elaborando dos forms en el cual en el primero habrá un dropdown para mostrar datos de una tabla de MySQL y al seleccionar uno de los registros, en el segundo form aparecerá su información en unos textbox y un dropdown para ser actualizados si es necesario.

De momento estoy teniendo dos problemas, uno al momento de querer actualizar me aparece un error de tipo "Undefined Index" y no esta enviando al procedimiento el ID.

Para ser más exacto este es el error que me aparece:

> Notice: Undefined index: cmbID in ...\conexionBD_ActualizarEmpleado.php on line 15
>   Error: call sp_ActualizarEmpleado('', 'Maria', 'Salas', 'Martinez', 'Salinas', '6631231234', 'correo@correo.com', ' 4 ')
>   Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'EmpleadoID' at row 1**

Y el código que tengo en este momento es este:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Actualizar un Registro de Empleado</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            <?php
                require_once("conexionBD_ActualizarEmpleado.php");
                $sql="SELECT empleado.Empleado_ID, empleado.Nombre, empleado.Segundo_Nombre, empleado.Apellido_Paterno, empleado.Apellido_Materno, empleado.Telefono, empleado.Correo_Electronico, empleado.Puesto_Puesto_ID, puesto.Nombre_Puesto FROM empleado inner join puesto on empleado.Puesto_Puesto_ID = puesto.Puesto_ID";
        $sql2="SELECT Puesto_ID, Nombre_Puesto FROM puesto";
                $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
            ?>
        </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos_Submenu.css">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#nombre').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('nombre'));
      $('#segnombre').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('segnombre'));
      $('#apaterno').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('apaterno'));
      $('#amaterno').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('amaterno'));
      $('#tel').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('tel'));
      $('#email').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('email'));
      $('#puesto').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('puesto'));
      $(function(){
          $('#selectdata').change(function(){
              $('#nombre').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('nombre'));
              $('#segnombre').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('segnombre'));
              $('#apaterno').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('apaterno'));
              $('#amaterno').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('amaterno'));
              $('#tel').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('tel'));
              $('#email').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('email'));
              $('#puesto').val($('#selectdata option:selected').data('puesto'));
          });
      });
      });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Actualizar Registro de Empleado</h1>
    <form class="form1" action="" method="POST">
        Empleado: <select name="cmbID" id="selectdata">
          <?php
            if($result->num_rows>0){
              while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '<option value=" '.$row['Empleado_ID'].'" data-nombre="'.$row['Nombre'].'" data-segnombre="'.$row['Segundo_Nombre'].'" data-apaterno="'.$row['Apellido_Paterno'].'" data-amaterno="'.$row['Apellido_Materno'].'" data-apaterno="'.$row['Apellido_Paterno'].'" data-tel="'.$row['Telefono'].'" data-email="'.$row['Correo_Electronico'].'" data-puesto="'.$row['Puesto_Puesto_ID'].'">'.$row['Empleado_ID'].'. '.$row['Nombre'].' '.$row['Segundo_Nombre'].' '.$row['Apellido_Paterno'].' '.$row['Apellido_Materno'].'</option>';
              }
            }
            $conn->close();
          ?></select><br /><br />
    </form>
    <br />
    <form class="form2" action="conexionBD_ActualizarEmpleado.php" method="POST">
            Nombre: <input type="text" name="txtNombre" maxlenght="45" id="nombre"/></br></br>
            Segundo Nombre: <input type="text" name="txtSegundoNom" maxlenght="45" id="segnombre"/></br></br>
            Apellido Paterno: <input type="text" name="txtApellidoPa" maxlenght="45" id="apaterno"></br></br>
            Apellido Materno: <input type="text" name="txtApellidoMa" maxlenght="45" id="amaterno"></br></br>
            Telefono: <input type="text" name="txtTelefono" maxlenght="45" id="tel"/></br></br>
            Correo Electronico: <input type="text" name="txtEmail" maxlenght="45" id="email"/></br></br>
            Puesto: <select name="cmbPuesto" id="puesto">
        <?php
                if($result2->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row=$result2->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<option value=" '.$row['Puesto_ID'].' "> '.$row['Nombre_Puesto'].' </option>';
                    }
                }
                $conn->close();
            ?>
      </select>
      <br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="btnActualiza" value="Actualizar Datos">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el código con la información de BD y la llamada al procedimiento:

```
    <?php
    $servername="127.0.0.1";
    $username="root";
    $password="password";
    $dbname="proyecto_hotel";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("La conexion fallo".$conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql="call sp_ActualizarEmpleado('".$_POST['cmbID']."', '".$_POST['txtNombre']."', '".$_POST['txtSegundoNom']."', '".$_POST['txtApellidoPa']."', '".$_POST['txtApellidoMa']."', '".$_POST['txtTelefono']."', '".$_POST['txtEmail']."', '".$_POST['cmbPuesto']."')";

    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "New record updated";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: ".$sql."</br>".$conn->error;
    }
?>
```

¿Hay alguna menera en como pueda obtener el ID de la primera forma (donde envio ese dato es en la variable 'cmbID' que es el nombre del dropdown) para usarlo en el procedimiento o algo que no este considerando en mi codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es por que el submit lo estas enviando desde el formulario 2, el cual no tiene el select cmbID, mi sugerencia es que crees en el form 2 un input de tipo hidden, al cual se asignes el valor del select cmbID cuando este cambie.

Primero recuerda agregar Jquery al tag Head del html

Todo el código de Javascript debe quedar algo así

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#selectdata').on('change', function() {
      $("#hiddendata").val(this.value);
    });

</script>
</head>
```

Y el form2 algo así

```
 <form class="form2" action="conexionBD_ActualizarEmpleado.php" method="POST">
            Nombre: <input type="text" name="txtNombre" maxlenght="45" id="nombre"/></br></br>
            Segundo Nombre: <input type="text" name="txtSegundoNom" maxlenght="45" id="segnombre"/></br></br>
            Apellido Paterno: <input type="text" name="txtApellidoPa" maxlenght="45" id="apaterno"></br></br>
            Apellido Materno: <input type="text" name="txtApellidoMa" maxlenght="45" id="amaterno"></br></br>
            Telefono: <input type="text" name="txtTelefono" maxlenght="45" id="tel"/></br></br>
            Correo Electronico: <input type="text" name="txtEmail" maxlenght="45" id="email"/></br></br>
            Puesto: <select name="cmbPuesto" id="puesto">
        <?php
                if($result2->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row=$result2->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<option value=" '.$row['Puesto_ID'].' "> '.$row['Nombre_Puesto'].' </option>';
                    }
                }
                $conn->close();
            ?>
      </select>
      <br/><br/>
       <input type="hidden" id="hiddendata" name="cmbID" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="btnActualiza" value="Actualizar Datos">
    </form>
```

Comment: o lo mas fácil es agregar el select directamente al form2, la verdad no se por que lo tienes en forms diferentes.